# Convert jpg images to .hdf5

Tags: python, image, jpeg

Answering my own question here for future reference.

I was recently working with a dataset of type `.jpg` images and needed to convert them to `.hdf5` images. I saw some answers for converting the other way around, but nothing from `.jpg` to `.hdf5`. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution looks like this

```
def convert_file(input_dir, filename, output_dir):
    filepath = input_dir + '/' + filename
    fin = open(filepath, 'rb')
    binary_data = fin.read()
    new_filepath = output_dir + '/' + filename[:-4] + '.hdf5'
    f = h5py.File(new_filepath)
    dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.dtype('uint8'))
    dset = f.create_dataset('binary_data', (100, ), dtype=dt)
    dset[0] = np.fromstring(binary_data, dtype='uint8')
```

I have a tool to do this at 
https://github.com/raguiar2/jpg_to_h5

Answer (score 1):

I also created my own mini library for handling h5 files. Here's the link:
https://github.com/ss4328/h5_manager_scripts

The script manages creating h5 from a directory, merging h5s as well as visualizing 12 images from a h5.